# How to emulate double tap on one tap?

Tags: android, click, double, tap

For example

```
   mainEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        int i = 0;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here something that causing double tap event
            }
        });
```

How can i archive that?

Comment: use timer thread in Android it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support double tap by default. You can kind of get the same effect by using a normal OnClickListener that stores a timestamp and checks to see if the stored value is close enough to the current time to count as a double click. You could even make your own Listener class that behaves this way. But I am unsure what you mean when you say: "here something that causing double tap event" Since nothing in android responds to double taps by default.

Comment: I just want that when user make tap on EditText program thought that user made two taps at the same place. maybe there are way to invoke onClick from onClick or something like that?

Comment: You would have to call onClick(View v) on whichever listener you set to the EditText. However keep in mind doing this is going to create recursion of your click method you'll need to make an if statement that will stop it from happening more than once.